# Calculate position of element relative to screen resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

My website has fixed width content size (1170px).
Right now the lightbox content has CSS "right" set to "0" (image 1).

[image]

But I need you to start where start content (image 2).

[image]

Well, in theory I know how to do that...

CSS

```css
right: (Width screen - 1170px)/2
```

Anybody can help me with some jquery or javascript or css code?

Take a look the site: http://iglesias.coroleu.com/

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you're asking. Can you expand?

Comment: The site is not reachable. Also, please provide some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
.mfp-container {
   right: calc((100% - 1170px) / 2);
}
.mfp-bg {
   right: calc((100% - 1170px) / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I get this correct, all you want to do is calculate this dynamically:

(screen width - 1170px ) / 2

The css calc() function can help you with that.

set this (vw means viewport width) :

```
right: calc(100vw - 1170px) / 2
```

More on calc => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Answer (score 1):

In general you can center content of a div (or a body) element by applying css:

```
width: 1170px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
```

You can apply it in css, or directly to the element with a style attribute.
What it does, is it sets the width of the content to 1170px and then lets the browser to auto-center if the parent element is wider.

BUT, I seriously suggest you to read some css tutorials. This question is way too basic.

Something like:
https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: You dont understand my problem. Dont worry. I solved with other aswers...